# ORA-19279 XPTY0004 - Xquery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, xml-namespaces, xmltable

I have next below xml message in CLOB column:

```
<Message type="Close Subscription" creationdatetime="15/01/2010 07:48" market="01" xmlns="http://test.org/">
  <Customer userId="data" market="01">
    <UserAccount>test@hotmail.com</UserAccount>
    <ExpireDate>15/02/2016 07:48:11</ExpireDate>
    <Member>
      <MemberReferency number="000003" digit="85" market="01" name="John Rambo"/>
    </Member>
    <Email Id="700">
      <Address>test@hotmail.com</Address>
      <IsConfirmed>True</IsConfirmed>
      <Privacies>
        <Privacy type="C" value="I"/>
        <Privacy type="M" value="I"/>
      </Privacies>
    </Email>
    <Newsletter mailService="NL">
      <language>N</language>
      <frequency>0</frequency>
      <promotion/>
      <origin/>
    </Newsletter>
  </Customer>
</Message>
```

For this xml message, I have twice the xml tag **privacy**

```
  <Privacies>
    <Privacy type="C" value="I"/>
    <Privacy type="M" value="T"/>
  </Privacies>
```

How can I get the value of privacy for only one of them without fetch the error?.

I mean, to get the privacy of the type='C'.

Now I'm using next below query that contain the error:

```
select Privacy
  from (select *
          from ta_gen.notification_log a,
               XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test.org/' AS "XML"),
                        '/XML:Message' passing xmltype(NTL_MSG) columns                            
                        Privacy VARCHAR2(1)     path 'XML:Customer/XML:Email/XML:Privacies/XML:Privacy/@value') O
         where a.ntl_type = 'Message')
```

NOTE: When the xml tag **privacy** is once in the xml message, the error is not raised.

Comment: What do you want to see if there is only one privacy node, but its type is M? In other words, do you you only want those with C, or do you want to prioritise C over M, but still show M if that is the only one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to happen when there is only an M-type node, you canb either search explicitly for the type attribute being C:

```
select x.privacy
from notification_log a
cross join XMLTable(XMLNamespaces('http://test.org/' AS "XML"),
  '/XML:Message'
  passing XMLType(ntl_msg)
  columns privacy varchar2(1)
    path 'XML:Customer/XML:Email/XML:Privacies/XML:Privacy[@type="C"]/@value') x
where a.ntl_type = 'Message';

PRIVACY
-------
I
```

Or you can extract the type and value for all privacy nodes via a second level of XMLTable, and then decide which to keep:

```
select min(x2.privacy) keep (dense_rank first order by x2.type) as privacy
from notification_log a
cross join XMLTable(XMLNamespaces('http://test.org/' AS "XML"),
  '/XML:Message' passing XMLType(ntl_msg)
  columns privacies XMLType path 'XML:Customer/XML:Email/XML:Privacies') x1
cross join XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test.org/' AS "XML"),
  'XML:Privacies/XML:Privacy'
  passing privacies
  columns type varchar2(1) path '@type',
    privacy varchar2(1) path '@value') x2
where a.ntl_type = 'Message';

PRIVACY
-------
I
```

If you ran the same query but instead did `select x2.type, x2.value from ...` then you'd see:

```
TYPE PRIVACY
---- -------
C    I      
M    I
```

.. and the `min(x2.privacy) keep (dense_rank first order by x2.type)` gets the value type from the 'lower' (according to string comparison) type value; which means it prioritises C over M if both exist, but will use either if there is only one

Comment: Thanks you very much, great solution.